# Recovery of QuickMemo+ data via SD - LG LEON bad screen

Tags: data-recovery, lg, broken-screen

I have an LG LEON which has a damaged screen & digitizer. USB Debug is off. I can access somewhat via PC. I tried a USB OTG cable & mouse as well as various software to get some critical data from the QuickMemo+ app.
I have a new LG LEON, all updated & I noticed all the data for the QuickMemo+ app seems to be on the SD card.
Ive used various apps & the LG software to attempt to get at the data for the QuickMemo app off the old phone.
Under Internal Storage/data there seems to be a folder for QM+ but all it contains is images & screencaps not the .db I need.
Question: can I swap SD cards & have my old QM+ data? Or will that just over write the data I want?
Should I get a MicroSD to usb adapter & attempt a backup first?
Other options besides spend more than the phone is worth on a digitizer repair?
I will, sa the data is critical...
Also - I attempted to use the LG PC backup software to transfer the QM+ app to PC & restore to my new phone.
I just got an empty Qm+ with no memos. I hope that i didn't damage my memos on the old system. 
Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Going to try a microSD to USB adapter on the PC & make a backup, hope i didnt do any damage using the lg pc backup software, and look for my .db file in linux & windows